# Почему компилятор не выдает ошибку аллоцирования памяти?

Tags: c, массивы, gcc, динамические-массивы, malloc

Почему компилятор(MinGW gcc 6.3) не выдает ошибку у кода ниже? Ведь по хорошему, что бы скомпилировать программу он должен знать сколько памяти она занимает, либо память должна динамически выделяться. Но в данном случае, ни одного, ни другого не происходит. Я просмотрел файл с расширением .s, но там тоже нет неявного вызова malloc. В общем, видимо я чего-то не понимаю.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int quantity_of_elements;
    printf("Enter the number of array elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity_of_elements);
    int array[quantity_of_elements];

    for(int i = 0; i < quantity_of_elements; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("%d", sizeof(array));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нестандартное расширение компилятора. Он просто выделяет нужное место на стеке.

Comment: @Harry VLA теперь уже стандартная фича языка (начиная с C99).

Comment: @yugr, теперь уже случился C11 и фича не совсем стандартная.

Comment: @yugr Я не обратил внимания, что это С, а не С++.

Comment: Но я так понимаю, это не рекомендуется к использованию в языке, потому что может переполняться стек?

Comment: Так ведь размер имеет значение :)